# Bash syntax for arbitrary file descriptors

Tags: command-line, bash

In the bash manual, opening an arbitrary file descriptor is described as:

> ```
> /dev/fd/fd
> ```
>
> If fd is a valid integer, file descriptor fd is duplicated.

Does this mean `/dev/fd/123`, or `dev/123/fd`, or `/dev/123/123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the DEVFS definitions, the correct location is `/dev/fd/NNN`. Note that using descriptors above 9 may cause problems as Bash uses some for its internal use. Permissions should also be respected.